# Quick question about chain homotopies.

Tags: definition, homological-algebra

In the definition of a chain homotopy (say $h$) between two chain maps (say $f$ and $g$), are the maps $h_i$ comprising the chain homotopy required to commute with all other maps involved (the $f_i$s, the $g_i$s, and the boundary maps in each complex)? Basically, in the associated diagram, are all the triangles commutative, or not necessarily? (I'd draw a picture, but I'm typing this on my phone, and that would take far too long). Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: By the way a good way to think about chain homotopies are as chain maps out of $$X_\bullet\otimes\mathcal{I}$$ such that $$\mathcal{I}$$ is the chain complex such that $$\mathcal{I}_0=<L,R>$$ (the notation $<x_1,x_2,\cdots x_n>$ denotes that free abelian group [or $R$-module] generated by the $x_i$), $$\mathcal{I}_1=<I>,$$ and $$\mathcal{I}_n=0\mbox{, otherwise}.$$ We define the boundary map, $$\partial:\mathcal{I}_1\to\mathcal{I}_0$$ to be $$\partial(I)=R-L.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that I would not expect that these triangles are commutative. Let us first reference the diagram and definition [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_category_of_chain_complexes#Definitions). The triangles I think that you might be referring to the $(d^{n-1}_A,h^n,f^{n-1})$ and $(d^{n-1}_A,h^n,g^{n-1})$. Indeed if both triangles commuted, then this would mean that $f=g$. Likewise is true if the $(h^n,d^{n-1}_B,f^n)$ and $(h^n,d^{n-1}_B,g^n)$ all commuted.